# iWork Numbers 09 increment a cell value

Tags: iwork

I am working with Numbers 09 and Applescript. 
I want to add a value in one cell to an existing value in another cell, replacing the existing value with the sum as a value. This would be similar to the copy/paste-add command in Excel. Thanks for your help. 
-Rob

Answer (score 0):

Got it...
I was trying to make it too difficult. Calling back to my ancient training in FORTRAN and Pascal.

copy 0.1 to xno
tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    tell document 1
        tell sheet 1
            tell table 1
                copy the value of cell "B2" to xno
                xno - 200
                copy xno to the value of cell "C2"
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell